# How to add an icon to a menu on vs extenion .VSCT

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vsct

How to add an icon to a menu on the first level.
 This is on the context menu of the solution explorer

```
<Commands package="guidSrpPkg">
<Menus>
  <Menu guid="guidSrpCmdSet" id="MenuSrp" priority="10">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDG_VS_CTXT_PROJWIN_SCOPE"/>
    <CommandFlag>DynamicVisibility</CommandFlag>
    <Strings>
      <ButtonText>My menu where I want a icon</ButtonText>
    </Strings>
  </Menu>
</Menus>
```

On Button i'ts possible with Icon element but not possible with Menu element ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to add an icon to a top menu or sub menu.